# When typing git push -u origin master, nothing happens. It is blinking without stopping

Tags: git, github, cmd, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When typing the command `git push -u origin master` nothing happens. Just keep blinking. It happens every time i push and i cannot continue after. I want to know how to fix this blinking problem.

Answer (score 0):

Configure a global git user and try again. If you already have then redo it and see if it helps